# Android listview over listview scrolling issue

Tags: android, listview, android-relativelayout

I am having the layout with 2 listviews 1 over another in a relative layout as follows

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

So as per addition of the view the 2nd listview is placed over the 1st listview as per client design.

Now my requirement is I want 2nd listview i.e listview placed above  is to be fixed and listview placed below should be scrollable because 1st listview has max 5 items. Currently it happening exactly opposite of this. I tried

> android:focusable="false"
>           android:clickable="false"

but no luck. Plese help me in solving this or tell me any other approach to this

Comment: Try putting both listviews under parentlayout linearLayout and give weight as .5 for both

Comment: I want listviews to be 1 above other so wrapping it in linearlayout wont solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

You might have to give the height of the ListView match_parent as well.
Consider using a LinearLayout for the 1st list, since you know there is a max of 5 items.

Also, it seems like you're not using the RelativeLayout properties to set the position of the child views which by default are align to top and left. Consider switching it out with a FrameLayout.

Comment: 1. are you saying that I should wrap 1st list it around Linear layout??  2. Framelayout cannot be used since I have the 2nd listview should be placed over the 1st so no point in switching list 3. tried wrap_content but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       >
    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This worked for me if I put 5 max values in `listView1` then it does not scroll and the below `listView2` scrolls.

Comment: as a said linearlayout wont work because I want 1 listview above another

Comment: If you want your listviews to be one above other.Then linearlayout with vertical orientation will be the best choice.It would be better if u add some image with ur ques showing your desired layout.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false" >

    </ListView>
    <ListView
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```